# How to get updated records in remote SQL Server and update them in my local server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a local SQL Server and a remote SQL Server. I want to when user updates records in remote SQL Server the equivalent records be updated in my local SQL Server.

How can I get updated records in remote SQL Server?

Just care about it, I can't add trigger or a `datetime` field to remote SQL Server.

Are there any useful information in sys tables for updated records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in mechanism(s) to do this is [Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx), your often better off doing this than rolling out your own solution.

Comment: Yes I know about replication, but are there any solutions to replicate just updated records?

Comment: Well none of them will keep shipping a complete copy of the DB to the subscriber, take a look at transactional replication http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx

Comment: It's better to say, I have two different databases. I'm writing a program for employers.the first database stores some basic information of employers but the second database which is written before stores some special information of employers. but some fields between two databases are the same. as like as name and family and.. .I want to when user insert information in first database these common fields be inserted as a record into second database and when user updates these fields in second database the equivalent fields be updated in first database,how can I use replication for this purpose?

Comment: Link server is a good idea when I want to insert from first database into second database, but what about the second database to first database. How do I get updated records from second database and then update them in first database too.

Comment: If you need to monitor changed rows you could add a `rowversion` column; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

Comment: My first databse is SQL 2008 R2 but the second one is 2000 version. Will it works in 2000 version? I found a website (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/) but it is not for each record. what is your idea about it?

Comment: @Morphy did u get the solution, i am in similar situation . my question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205361/is-replecation-possible-if-publisher-stay-offline-and-subscriber-is-online-datab/9216180#9216180