# replication between  offline publisher  and online subscriber?

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

i read a lot about replication on MSDN and stackoverflow. and i just want to use snapshot replication for my client. my question is that i never get the idea how
 **is it possible that my client database  which is source for my web application database can stay offline and subscriber can get the data from that offline database.**

internet is always working on that client machine but there database is accessible only in there LAN not on WAN ? so how my online database(subscriber) find that database(publication and distributor) ?

i am not very much clear that how to put this  question in a understandably language to others so if any body can edit it would be great appreciable ?

**EDIT**

I need this because client have a local database which have very high number of transaction regarding booking of a travel agency and he want that on website he show some statics from his window application database so we want to replicate this offline database to our online database and from there we can generate reports for him..

**EDIT**

is this can be done with [Change Tracking(CT) and Change Data Capture(CDC)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2009/03/24/sql-server-2008-change-tracking-ct-and-change-data-capture-cdc.aspx)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look into [Publishing Data over the Internet Using VPN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152569.aspx).